# How to make button for smoothDivScroll

Tags: jquery, smooth-scrolling

I want to make 2 simple clickable links using  tags to change the scrolling direction of slides using the JQuery SmoothDivScroll of Thomas Kahn. I would like to make the scrolling directions to the RIGHT and to the LEFT both to be clickable links, but don't know how to do this. Can anyone help?

The code I have so far is on http://www.festifood.nl/test.html

Thanks

Comment: Those look like they work...? Can you be more specific as to what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Also, if you can provide your code too so I can take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

Below is one type of code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#makeMeScrollable").smoothDivScroll({ 
                mousewheelScrolling: true,
                manualContinuousScrolling: true,
                visibleHotSpotBackgrounds: "always",
                autoScrollingMode: "onstart"
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Below this link shows what that code looks like and how to code it:

http://www.smoothdivscroll.com/

Answer (score 0):

Here is how it works. At the end of your "$(document).ready(function(){"-function add:

```
$("#right").click(function() {
  $("#makeMeScrollable").smoothDivScroll("option","autoScrollDirection","right");
});

$("#left").click(function() {
  $("#makeMeScrollable").smoothDivScroll("option","autoScrollDirection","left");    
});

$("#backandforth").click(function() {
  $("#makeMeScrollable").smoothDivScroll("option","autoScrollDirection","backandforth");    
});
```

### Ok, What does that do?

1. You defined spans with ID's as "left", "right" and so on (e.g. `<span id="left">left</span>`). In jQuery you select them via a selector, which is a string describing what is to be selected. To select an element by ID the string starts with "#" followed by the ID. To execute a selector use $(selector) as $("#left") which selects the <span>-Tag with id="left";
2. We want to assign a handler function for the click event to this selected element. So we write `$("#left").click( ... );`. And as a parameter we put in a function without parameters, which will be executed when the <span> is clicked on.
3. Inside that event handler function we change the options of the smoothDivScroll.

### More Info

- The options are explained here: http://www.smoothdivscroll.com/options.html
- And how to change options is explained here: http://www.smoothdivscroll.com/alteringOptions.html

### Click vs. OnMouseOver

If you want to react to the mouseover event, just write `.mouseover(...)` instead of `.click(...)`

#### Additionally: Bug in your CSS?

You should also fix your CSS, add a ";" behind 330px; and a "float: left;":

```
#makemescrollable {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 330px;
  float: left;
}
```